# Can I use an old TV as a monitor for Mac Mini?

Tags: mac-mini

I have an old TV with following sockets:

Front:

[image: Sockets on the front]

Back:

[image: Sockets on the back]

Can I use this TV as a monitor for Mac Mini (2012) ? If so, do I need any adapters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mac Mini sends out digital video through HDMI or the Thunderbolt port. Your old TV has Composite ports, which take analogue signals.

You could theoretically use something like this: [ViewHD Universal HDMI to Composite / S-Video Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AQ4HF7G), but I havent tested it myself. The picture quality would probably be really bad.

Answer (score 1):

An "old TV" that appears to lack any ports other than composite video will most likely not be able to display a computer image at a resolution greater than 640 x 480. (It is a 480i image.)

I'm also pretty sure that Mac Minis made after 2009 (Intel Core 2 Duos) have a minimum resolution of 800 x 600. They don't go down lower than that.

Check your own Mac Mini by going to System Preferences > Displays > Display > Scaled and look for the lowest available resolution to confirm this.

Your best bet would be to buy some kind of intermediary device like an AV receiver (Yamaha, Denon, Pioneer) to take input from your computer and send output to your TV.